# ng build issue getting node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-angular-grids/

Tags: angular, cordova, ej2-syncfusion

```
I am getting the below error tried deleting package-lock.json, @syncfusion and reinstalled using
```

npm install @syncfusion/ej2-base

```
but still I am facing issues while running ng build
Error:`
node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-angular-grids/src/pager/pager.component.d.ts:37:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/gopichand/experiment/bhuwanbashel-ualcancancer-00c201113557/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration'.

37     static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<PagerComponent, "ejs-pager", never, { "cssClass": "cssClass"; "currentPage": "currentPage"; "customText": "customText"; "enableExternalMessage": "enableExternalMessage"; "enablePagerMessage": "enablePagerMessage"; "enablePersistence": "enablePersistence"; "enableQueryString": "enableQueryString"; "enableRtl": "enableRtl"; "externalMessage": "externalMessage"; "locale": "locale"; "pageCount": "pageCount"; "pageSize": "pageSize"; "pageSizes": "pageSizes"; "template": "template"; "totalRecordsCount": "totalRecordsCount"; }, { "click": "click"; "created": "created"; "dropDownChanged": "dropDownChanged"; }, ["template"], never>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-angular-grids/src/pager/pager.module.d.ts:8:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/gopichand/experiment/bhuwanbashel-ualcancancer-00c201113557/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

8     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<PagerModule, never>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-angular-grids/src/pager/pager.module.d.ts:9:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/gopichand/experiment/bhuwanbashel-ualcancancer-00c201113557/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration'.

9     static ɵmod: i0.ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration<PagerModule, [typeof i1.PagerComponent], [typeof i2.CommonModule], [typeof i1.PagerComponent]>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-angular-grids/src/pager/pager.module.d.ts:10:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/gopichand/experiment/bhuwanbashel-ualcancancer-00c201113557/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectorDeclaration'.

10     static ɵinj: i0.ɵɵInjectorDeclaration<PagerModule>;
```

```
page.ts
public countryFields: Object = {text: 'CountryName', value: 'CountryId'};
  public countryData: Object[] = [
    {CountryName: 'US', CountryId: '1'},
    {CountryName: 'UK', CountryId: '2'}
  ];
```

I am trying to build a dropdown list.

html

```
          <div style="margin:10% 40%; width:250px;">
            <div id="dropdownlist_country">
                <ejs-dropdownlist [dataSource]='countryData' [fields]='countryFields' palceholder='Select a country'></ejs-dropdownlist>
            </div>
          </div>
          
`module.ts``
```

import { GridModule } from '@syncfusion/ej2-angular-grids';

@NgModule({
imports: [GridModule]

```
`your text`
```